# How to bold, color, and remove italics on an item at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just wanted to know whether there was a way to remove italics, color, and bold an item in Minecraft at the same time. I know how to do them individually, I'm just unsure how to put them together properly. I'm trying to give myself a player head that I can do this with along with the SkullOwner tag:

`/give @a minecraft:player_head{SkullOwner:speedysky123}`

This is what I would like to make the color green, remove the italics, and embolden.

Comment: Have you looked at the JSON section of the commands article on the Minecraft wiki? It tells you all of that and much more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please include the Minecraft version you are using when asking a command replated question because the syntax has changed in version 1.13.

For 1.13 and above:

```
/give @a minecraft:player_head{SkullOwner:speedysky123,display:{Name:'{"text":"speedysky123\'s","color":"green","italic":"false","bold":"true"}'}}
```

for 1.12, this is where it gets tricky. To get colors in 1.12, people used color codes which look like this "§2some text". A color code is composed of the section symbol (§) and a letter/number representing a specific color (you can find all the color codes on the Minecraft wiki). The problem with this is that the in-game chat and command blocks don't support this symbol so you can't type it. A workaround would be to use external software such as NBTExplorer or McEdit to paste the color codes in, but since you want to give this item to all players, I don't think this will be of much use to you. Long story short, I don't think you can achieve this in 1.12 without using external software or tricky methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. However, I didn't include the version because I figured one could discern from the format of the command which version I was specifying.