# How do i get an item with a bold / italic colored name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to get a colored item but i cant find out how to get a bold and colored item at the same time.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please state what you have done before, then we can help you.

Comment: Welcome to the Arqade. There are multiple questions surrounding this topic that already have answers ([here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362696/how-to-bold-color-and-remove-italics-on-an-item-at-the-same-time) is one example).

Comment: ExpertCoder14 I found out how to make it colored but if i ad bold or italic it will just make it colored.

Comment: Taco, thanks for the info but im looking for it on 1.17 / 1.17.1

Comment: @Night_bubble342 The question we linked answers for 1.13 and above, including 1.17.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like that?

**/give @p minecraft:egg{display:{Lore:['{"text":"Egg","color":"red","bold":true}']}} 1**